# How to prevent __init__ from running in a directory?

Tags: python

Sorry if this question is impossible, I'm sort of new to python. When I run the code `from outer import inner` in a separate program, both outer and inner are printed(as expected). Is there any way to prevent this, without changing the `__init__` methods? I'm asking this question in case I'm ever working with a `__init__` statement in a built-in module, and need to overwrite it /stop it from running for some reason. All the other questions on SO(that I found, at least) were related to classes, not modules. Thanks in advance!

My module structure:

```
outer
├── __init__.py (prints out "outer")
├── inner
│   ├── __init__.py (prints out "inner")
│   └── other_code.py
```

Comment: What is the expected output? No output? :)

Comment: The `__init__.py` file is how Python navigates directories to perform importing. When you import a module, you will automatically import anything contained in that file. If there is code that executes, such as a print statement, and not just function/class definitions, it will execute on every import. I'm not sure there is a way to prevent that happening other than refraining from putting such code in that particular file.

Comment: It's worth noting that `__init__.py` files don't really have anything to do with `__init__` methods in classes, other than the `__init__` name. The right term to use for learning about the files is "packages".

Comment: Rephrasing, the question is essentially "how do I stop python from importing a module in the way that it imports modules". If you provide a more detailed example to a particular issue, we could perhaps provide you with a solution.

Comment: Does this work?: `if __name__ == '__main__: do_stuff()'`

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just delete the `__init__.py` files? They're not necessary in modern Python with implicit namespace packages; they're allowed (and their code runs if non-empty), but they're pointless if you don't need/want anything to run.

Comment: @a1426 , If one of the answers helped you (**not** talking about myself in particular), feel free to slap that check mark near the up vote/down vote button to mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Warning: Answer kinda useless

I think this would help (I'm ok at python):

In your outer's `__init__.py` (the one you don't want to call `print('outer')`, replace the code with this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('outer')
```

That's kinda useless since then `__init__.py` would never be able to run. (I tried)

So the easy way is to leave it blank :|.